# Using Flow, the list is not reloaded in the recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, kotlin-flow

I am training with a simple app to show movies, I use an MVVM pattern and Flow.

#### Problem

This is my home, filterable through chips
[image: Home]

I click on a movie , the details screen comes up then I go back to the home and this is the result:
[image: no content]

Using logcat the home screen gets the list of movies to show but is not shown in the recyclerview (which uses diffUtil).

Below is the code for my fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class Home2Fragment : Fragment() {
    private val TAG = Home2Fragment::class.simpleName
    private var _binding: FragmentHome2Binding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentHome2Binding
        get() = _binding!!
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentHome2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.apply {

            initChipGroupSpecificMovieList()

            val adapter = MovieAdapter()
            sectionRv.setHasFixedSize(true)
            sectionRv.adapter = adapter
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                    viewModel.movieListBySpecification.collectLatest {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: received list")
                        adapter.addItems(it)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private fun FragmentHome2Binding.initChipGroupSpecificMovieList() {
        val sortByMap = HomeViewModel.Companion.MovieListSpecification.values()
        chipGroup.removeAllViews()
        for (specification in sortByMap) {
            val chip = Chip(context)
            chip.isCheckable = true
            chip.id = specification.ordinal
            chip.text = getString(specification.nameResource)
            chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked)
                    viewModel.setMovieListSpecification(specification)
            }
            chipGroup.addView(chip)
        }
        chipGroup.check(sortByMap.lastIndex - sortByMap.size + 1)//check first element

    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

it seems at the line of code where I try to insert the list of movies in the adapter this doesn't add them because maybe via diffUtil it finds that it is the previous list and so it doesn't load it. However it doesn't show the previous one either, possible solutions?

Comment: try to remove sectionRv.setHasFixedSize(true)

Comment: Can you show your adapter code? I suspect the problem is in there.

Comment: Solved by removing setHasFixedSize(true)

Answer (score 0):

as java code you can use this

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(it.size() > 0) {
            adapter.addItems(it)
        }
    }
```